# Disable component license check

Tags: vb6

Could you please advice, can I disable third-party component license checks in Visual Basic 6 ?

I have a task to compile VB6 project with big amount of legacy code and this project uses some third-party DLL and OCX components. We found some versions of this components, but when I try to build EXE file I get following compilation errors: "Cannot load control FrameTimer; license not found."

Can I disable somehow this license checks from VB6 Studio setting or registry?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to get a licence for the control or replace the 3rd party controls with standard controls.

Or hack the controls and disable the security check feature somehow. If you are compiling legacy code for a client then I suspect they will have had a licence for the controls at some time in the past, and you'll have to ask them to find the information.

You can't disable anything in the IDE, otherwise how would 3rd part control vendors have made money, and enforced the need for registering of their controls ?

Comment: +1. You may simply need to install the 3rd party controls properly.